# Compute $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{-n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

Compute:

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{-n^2}$$

My attempt:

First rewrite the summation as a limit and a summation:

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=N}^k e^{-n^2}$$

Then notice that the expression inside the limit is bounded above by $(k-N)e^{-N^2}$ since $e^{-n^2}$ is decreasing.

Taking the limits together we see that this converges to $0$.

However, I'm not actually sure what I mean by "taking the limits together". Assuming the limits can be exchanged, I think it is well defined to take $N$ and $k$ to their limiting value at the same time.

I could use some feedback on my approach.

Comment: "Taking the limits together" isn't correct; for example, this same proposed proof would prove that the harmonic series converges. If you take the $k$-limit first (as given by the notation) then it reduces to the original problem; while some justification would be needed to switch the order of the limits and take the $N$-limit first. Hint: what happens if you write $\sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{-n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} e^{-n^2}$ before taking the limit as $N\to\infty$?

Comment: It almost feels like we could apply direct substitution and and then just find $e^{-\infty^2}\to 0$.

Comment: More generally, if $\sum a_n$ is any convergent series, then $$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n = 0$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare to a geometric series: $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{-n^2} < \sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{-n} = \frac{e^{-N}}{1 - e^{-1}} \xrightarrow[N \to \infty]{} 0.$$

Comment: A lot simpler than mine.

Answer (score 5):

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{-n^2}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-(n+N)^2}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-N^2-2nN-n^2}\\
&=e^{-N^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-2nN-n^2}\\
&\lt e^{-N^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-2nN}\\
&\lt e^{-N^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (e^{-2N})^n\\
&\lt e^{-N^2}\dfrac1{1-e^{-2N}}\\
&\lt e^{-N^2}\dfrac1{1-e^{-2}}
\qquad\text{for } N > 1\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$